# QuickBooks SDK: error running MCInvoiceAddQBFC sample

Tags: quickbooks

When I run the MCInvoiceAddQBFC sample from the Quickbooks SDK version 8 I get the following error:

```
An error requires the application to close:
Logging File: CRITICAL
Log File: C:\ProgramData\Intuit\QBSDK\log\MCInvoiceAddQBFCLog.txt
Exception Caught:
The version of QBXML that was requested is not supported or is unknown.
```

I get this error after Quickbooks pops a message asking me to confirm access for the sample application. I can't see the log file the error message mentions.

Answer (score 1):

What version of QuickBooks are you running? Does your version of QuickBooks in fact support the version of qbXML that the request is using?

http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_qbxml_versions

Comment: Quickbooks Premier Multicurrency Edition in Canada. Digging down in the sample code I see it uses version 1 of qbXML (major 1, minor 0).

Comment: What version of QuickBooks Premier Multicurrency Edition in Canada? Older versions of Canadian QuickBooks only support CA1.0, CA2.0, or CA3.0. See the link I posted in my post.